# Open a tab to the left of the current tab using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement to make the new tab open to the left of the current tab. This is the code I tried which opens a new tab to the right of the current Tab. Kindly check and give suggestions.

```
window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I have seen browser plugins that do something similar though.

Comment: Depending on the browser and how every person configures his/her browser, this might not be possible.